Stryker searching for .NET 6.0 file in .NET 8.0 solution (WorkerExtensions.AssemblyInfo.cs)
I'm trying to run Stryker in my .NET 8.0 solution which contains an App Service Proxy project and Azure Functions project but it is looking for a file in the net6.0 release folder. This file doesn't appear to be available in the net8.0 folder either
Deployment of pipeline seems to fail on mutation testing with stryker on my Functions due to error:
An error occurred during the mutation test run System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:...\obj\Release\net6.0\WorkerExtensions.AssemblyInfo.cs'
How can I get Stryker to run mutation tests on my solution?
